# Is it possible to save a function in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I know this task can easily be solved by just adding "bild1", "bild2" and "bild3" to the onclick events, but I wanted to try and solve this with an array, but it doesn't seem to work.. What am I doing wrong? Can functions even be saved in an array?

Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="bild1.png">
        <button onclick="meinArray[0]">Bild1</button>
        <button onclick="meinArray[1]">Bild2</button>
        <button onclick="meinArray[2]">Bild3</button>
        <script>
            let meinArray = new Array();
            meinArray[0] = bild1();
            meinArray[1] = bild2();
            meinArray[2] = bild3();

            <!-- let i = 0; -->
            function bild1(){
                document.images[0].src = "bild1.png";
            }

            function bild2(){
                document.images[0].src = "bild2.png";
            }

            function bild3(){
                document.images[0].src = "bild3.png";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do not execute them: ```meinArray[0] = bild1;```

Comment: @demkovych Post as answer

Comment: Even then it doesn't work..

Comment: You also need to call the function though in the `onclick="meinArray[0]()"` etc...

Answer (score 1):

You need to save a reference to a functions instead of executing them:

```
meinArray[0] = bild1;
meinArray[1] = bild2;
meinArray[2] = bild3;
```

and then execute them like:

```
<button onclick="meinArray[0]()">Bild1</button>
```

Comment: Hell yeah, that did the trick! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to one function and store only values in array rather than writing lots of functions for every new images

```js
function bild(index){ document.images[0].src = index; }
```

```html
<img src="bild1.png">
<button onclick="bild('bild1.png')">Bild1</button>
<button onclick="bild('bild2.png')">Bild2</button>
<button onclick="bild('bild3.png')">Bild3</button>
```

Comment: While the images are numbered, what about: `function bild(index){  document.images[0].src = "bild"+(index+1)+".png"; }` and then forget about the array.

Comment: I don't prefer to start with "build"+  it may be guid and dynamic images in  the future. So giving images link directly is better than this.